# comparing the names of files (of different extensions) in two directories and removing the files which names are not in both directories

Tags: windows, directory, compare, filenames

I have two Folders A, B:
A contains files with extension .stl, B contains files with extension .gcode
the files in both folders share the same name, however folder A has more files than B.
I want to remove all files from folder A, whose names are not in folder B so that at the end both folders have the same files of identical names.

Comment: What operating system are we talking about here?

Comment: i have windows 10

Comment: if you're willing to use Powershell, I think this is possible. I found a couple of articles to review which I think will get you close to a solution: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/04/14/contents-of-two-folders-with-powershell.aspx and https://serverfault.com/questions/532065/how-do-i-diff-two-folders-in-windows-powershell. You would then need to just delete the files in A which don't exist in B.